# ansible - cant set wallpaper in xfce4 with xfconf "failed to init libxfconf "

Tags: ansible, xfce

I try to set a wallpaper on Debian Systems with ansible on xfce4 desktops. For this I looked up the official documentation: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/xfconf_module.html

My Task:

```
  - name: set wallpaper
    become_user: odin
    xfconf:
      channel: "xfce4-desktop"
      property: "/backdrop/screen0/{{item}}/image-path"
      value_type: "string"
      value: ['/usr/share/backgrounds/xfce/802192.jpg']
    loop:
      - monitor0
      - monitor1
      - monitorDP-1
      - monitoreDP-1
```

I receive the following error:

```
XFConfException: xfconf-query failed with error (rc=1): Failed to init libxfconf: Error spawning command line “dbus-launch --autolaunch=2e66f568a1c34fda92dcec58e724b679 --binary-syntax --close-stderr”: Child process exited with code 1.

failed: [localhost] (item=monitoreDP-1) => {
    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
    "changed": false,
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "channel": "xfce4-desktop",
            "force_array": false,
            "property": "/backdrop/screen0/monitoreDP-1/image-path",
            "state": "present",
            "value": [
                "/usr/share/backgrounds/xfce/802192.jpg"
            ],
            "value_type": [
                "string"
            ]
        }
    },
    "item": "monitoreDP-1",
    "msg": "Module failed with exception: xfconf-query failed with error (rc=1): Failed to init libxfconf: Error spawning command line “dbus-launch --autolaunch=2e66f568a1c34fda92dcec58e724b679 --binary-syntax --close-stderr”: Child process exited with code 1.",                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
    "output": {
        "ansible_facts": {
            "xfconf": {}
        },
        "cmd_args": [
            "/usr/bin/xfconf-query",
            "--channel",
            "xfce4-desktop",
            "--property",
            "/backdrop/screen0/monitoreDP-1/image-path"
        ],
        "force_lang": "C",
        "rc": 1,
        "stderr": "Failed to init libxfconf: Error spawning command line “dbus-launch --autolaunch=2e66f568a1c34fda92dcec58e724b679 --binary-syntax --close-stderr”: Child process exited with code 1.\n",
        "stdout": ""
    },
    "vars": {
        "cmd_args": [
            "/usr/bin/xfconf-query",
            "--channel",
            "xfce4-desktop",
            "--property",
            "/backdrop/screen0/monitoreDP-1/image-path"
        ]
    }
}
```

I thought about copying the xml config for xfce4-desktop on to every machine, but not every machine has the same screen "monitor" property.

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work. Seems like running the task as root was doing the trick.

Answer (score 0):

The xfce modification works as root for me as well with the following approach:

```
- name: Copy wallpaper file
  copy:
    src: files/wallpaper.jpg
    dest: /usr/share/backgrounds/xfce/debian-wallpaper.jpg
    owner: root
    group: root
  when: ansible_distribution == "Debian"

- name: Change wallpaper
  become: true
  xfconf:
    channel: xfce4-desktop
    property: /backdrop/screen0/monitoreDP-1/workspace0/last-image
    value: ["/usr/share/backgrounds/xfce/debian-wallpaper.jpg"]
    value_type: string
  when: ansible_distribution == "Debian"
```

This will configure the xfce files in `/root/.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/xfce4-desktop.xml` though.

I was not able to do it for another user USERNAME, besides with this workaround:

```
- name: Copy xfce4 desktop xml files from root to user
  copy:
    src: /root/.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/xfce4-desktop.xml
    dest: /home/USERNAME/.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/xfce4-desktop.xml
    owner: USERNAME
    group: USERNAME
    force: yes
  when: ansible_distribution == "Debian"
```

If anybody know how to use xfconf module in a better way to overcome this workaround, please let me know.